# "Unable to locate package source vsupdate_KB2829760" Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Update 5

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have installed Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.  Then tried to update Nuget Package Manager, which redirected me to download `VS2013.5.exe` from microsoft. But when I try to install the update I get the error:

[image: VS2013 Update 5 Error]

None of the options worked. I even tried to locate the folder `vsupdate_kb2829760` from the DVD, and could not find it. Some of the answers pointed out that WebDeploy is needed because of some SSL or Certificate issue. I downloaded and installed `WebDeploy_amd64_en-US.msi` but that did nothing to resolve the issue, even after I have restarted.

Some of the answers I found mention Visual Studio 2012 Update 4, which does not seem to be applicable to the update I am trying to run.

How do I resolve this issue?

PS: I also tried un-installing VS2013 Ultimate and installed VS2013 Professional, but got the same issue.

Comment: I'm in the same boat as you are trying to setup my new work laptop. It looks like Update 4 is available but not Update 5. I guess I'll go with 4 for now.

Comment: I ended up giving up and installed vs 2019 community @FranklinKesler

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else experiencing this problem I found this [link](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202013) that contains all the Visual Studio 2013 downloads. I was able to download the full Update 5 disc image and install it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same error but with a different missing file. The issue was that I wasn't mounting the installer's iso properly, see [this thread](https://forum.yoyogames.com/index.php?threads/unable-to-locate-package-source.91915/).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30659874)

Answer (score 0):

copy the "packages" folder from your install (mounted ISO or whatever) into the directory you are running the VS2013.4 (or version)